# OpenCV Ubuntu - remove "init done" and "opengl support available" messages

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, opengl, codeblocks

I've installed OpenCV 3.2.0 on Ubuntu (using Code::Blocks as an IDE) and it seems like whenever I use imshow, the following messages are displayed to the console:

init done

opengl support available

Is there some way of getting rid of both of them? They're quite annoying since my program is mainly used through the console.